# Удаление символа переноса строки в зависимости от содержимого следующей строчки

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Прошу помощи реализации функционала удаления, в текстовом файле, символа переноса строки в строках которые начинаются "nazwa =" и "khnazwa =".

Пример:

> nazwa = Any
>
> text
>
> location = any

Должно выглядеть так:

> nazwa = Any text
>
> location = any

Пример 2:

> khnazwa = Any
>
> text
>
> khadres = any

Должно выглядеть так:

> khnazwa = Any text
>
> khadres = any

Оригинальная часть документа (как видно строчка "nazwa =" разделена на две линии, а после прохода программы - это должна быть одна линия):

```
Kontrahent{
    Notatka_Dl{
        opis =
    }
    id =65
    flag =0
    subtyp =0
    znacznik =68
    info =N
    osoba =
    kod =Cerrad
    nazwa = Spolka
z Ograniczona Odpowiedzialnoscia
    miejscowosc =Starachowice
    dom =
    lokal =
    imie =
    bnazwa =
    bkonto =
    negoc =N
    grupacen =5
    typ_naliczania =netto
    typ_ceny =B
    upust =0
    limit =0
    limitkwota =0.00
    limitwaluta =
    rejestr_platnosci =BANK
    forma_platnosci =przelew 14 dni
    stanpl =0.00
    stannl =0.00
    zapas =
    NazwaRodzaju =Kontrahenci?
}
```

Вижу такую логику процесса. Ищем строчку, что начинается на "nazwa =" и проверяем начало следующей, если она содержит "location =" идем дальше, а если нет, удаляем знак переноса строки в строчке с "nazwa =" и идем дальше.

Также и в строчке, что начинается на "khnazwa =" проверяем начало следующей, если она содержит "khadres =" идем дальше, а если нет, удаляем знак переноса строки в строчке с "khnazwa =" и идем дальше.

Спасибо всем кто приложил усилия к решению задачи.

Comment: А что такое `знак переноса` ?

Comment: @splash58 это "\n"

Comment: Символ после которого текст начинается в следующей строке. В C# обозначается \n

Comment: В чем у Вас возникли сложности реализации? Что Вы пробовали? Пример кода. . .

Comment: Только подошел к изучению С# и момент после считывания строки с первым совпадением, переход на вторую, а самое главное, при условии, что вторая строчка не имеет "khadres =" в случае с "khnazwa =", и начинается действие возврата на предыдущую и выполнение удаления - для меня полная темень.

Comment: Не можете запустить наверно потому что у Вас нету метода Main().. Вам компилятор об этом должен писать. Смотрите внимательней. И Вам бы лучше с чего нибудь по проще начать.. Судя по всему данная задача ещё не для Вашего уровня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TextFile1.txt**

```
Kontrahent{
    Notatka_Dl{
        opis =
    }
    id =65
    flag =0
    subtyp =0
    znacznik =68
    info =N
    osoba =
    kod =Cerrad
    nazwa = Spolka
z Ograniczona Odpowiedzialnoscia
    miejscowosc =Starachowice
    dom =
    lokal =
    imie =
    bnazwa =
    bkonto =
    negoc =N
    grupacen =5
    typ_naliczania =netto
    typ_ceny =B
    upust =0
    limit =0
    limitkwota =0.00
    limitwaluta =
    rejestr_platnosci =BANK
    forma_platnosci =przelew 14 dni
    stanpl =0.00
    stannl =0.00
    zapas =
    NazwaRodzaju =Kontrahenci?
```

> 

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var strings = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt");

    var newStrings = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        if (strings[i].Trim().StartsWith("nazwa") || strings[i].Trim().StartsWith("khnazwa"))
        {
            if (!strings[i + 1].Contains("="))
            {
                newStrings.Add(strings[i] + " " + strings[i + 1]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            newStrings.Add(strings[i]);
        }
    }

    string[] output = newStrings.ToArray();            
    File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", output);
}
```

**output.txt**

```
Kontrahent{
    Notatka_Dl{
        opis =
    }
    id =65
    flag =0
    subtyp =0
    znacznik =68
    info =N
    osoba =
    kod =Cerrad
    nazwa = Spolka z Ograniczona Odpowiedzialnoscia
    miejscowosc =Starachowice
    dom =
    lokal =
    imie =
    bnazwa =
    bkonto =
    negoc =N
    grupacen =5
    typ_naliczania =netto
    typ_ceny =B
    upust =0
    limit =0
    limitkwota =0.00
    limitwaluta =
    rejestr_platnosci =BANK
    forma_platnosci =przelew 14 dni
    stanpl =0.00
    stannl =0.00
    zapas =
    NazwaRodzaju =Kontrahenci?
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но суть в том, что нужно работать конкретно с строками "nazwa =" и "khnazwa =" ибо в документе 15к строк и практически в каждой есть знак =.

Comment: Тут уже предложили много решений. Если ничего не подходит, возможно есть смысл выложить исходный файл, а не 4 строки из него, чтобы понять всю задачу.

Comment: Ну так можно добавить  if ((s.StartsWith("nazwa ") || (s.StartsWith("khnazwa ")) && s.Contains("="))

Comment: Вы правы, так и сделал, выложил часть оригинала документа.

Comment: Отредактировал свое сообщение. Пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Еще, в общем виде, можно сделать так:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            const string text = 
@"nazwa = Zarzycki
Help In Road
miejscowosc = any
khnazwa = Cerrad
Community Health Systems
khadres = any
";
            var newText = Regex.Replace(text, "(.+)\\r\\n([^=]+)\\r", "$1 $2");
            Console.WriteLine(newText);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё один вариант (обновил с обновлением условия):

```
IEnumerable<string> ProcessText(IEnumerable<string> original)
{
    string hold = null;
    foreach (var s in original)
    {
        if (s.StartsWith("location =") && hold != null)
        {
            yield return hold;
            hold = null;
        }
        if (hold != null)
            s = hold + " " + s;
        if (s.StartsWith("nazwa =") || s.StartsWith("khnazwa ="))
            hold = s;
        else
            yield return s;
    }
    if (hold != null)
        yield return hold;
}
```

Comment: Не могу проверить Ваш код, пожалуйста отобразите с реализацией кода открытия файла из c:\example.txt и сохранения в c:\example2.txt. Спасибо.

Comment: @IgKos: `File.WriteLines(@"c:\example2.txt", ProcessText(File.ReadLines(@"c:\example.txt")));`

Answer (score 0):

Ваша задача элементарна.

1. Считываете файл построчно в массив строк
2. Пробегаетесь по массиву строк и приклеиваете текущую строку к предыдущей, если текущая строка не содержит знака `=`. Если приклеивание произошло - удаляем текущую строку.
3. Записываем получившийся массив в файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.Linq;

class P
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "khnazwa = Cerrad \n Community Health Systems \n khadres = any";

        System.Console.WriteLine(str);

        System.Console.WriteLine(PrepereSting(str));
    }

    private static string PrepereSting(string str)
    {
        string[] strings = str.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strings[i].StartsWith("nazwa") || strings[i].StartsWith("khnazwa"))
            {
                strings[i] = string.Concat(strings[i] + strings[i + 1] + "\n");

                strings[i + 1] = string.Empty;
            }
        }


        return string.Join("", strings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо "\n" лучше использовать `Environment.NewLine`, а разбивку по строкам осуществлять, передавая строчку в `StringReader` и вызывая метод `ReadLine`.

Comment: Возникла проблема в том, что в документе имеется очень много полей с nazwa (bnazwa, odnazwa, NazwaKatalogu и т. д.). Есть ли возможность открыть текстовый документ, в нем найти секцию Kontrahent{ ... } и уже здесь начать исполнений кода удаления знака переноса строки?

Comment: @IgKos Конечно есть. Используйте `System.IO.FileStream`.